# Add 'To Do' back into the left navigation pane of Outlook PWA?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, progressive-web-app

Outlook on the web [contains a left navigation pane](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-tasks-in-outlook-on-the-web-f8d35330-64e4-4a7b-bcdc-8d85906e7a24) which accesses useful apps such as Teams and Calendar. 'To Do' was there as well but has now vanished - how can I add 'To Do' back into the left navigation pane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the top navigation bar that contains the Search box - there is now an icon captioned 'My Day'. From there click 'To Do'.